# How to compare two fields in a preprocess_field()

Tags: 7, datetime, entities, theming

I need to compare two fields using template_preprocess_field().

I've got a field date and a boolean field.
Field date collect start and end date but if it's one day event, I need to show "start date - one day"

If you don't collect the end date, it will be the same date of the start date.
Of course I can compare start date and end date and if they are the same I will show "one day" but if the event is still running (so I won't collect the end date), I should show "on air"

So I'm trying this

```
function bartik_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

  //here I call the date field
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_duration') { 
    $starttotime = time($variables['element']['#items'][0]['value']); // convert it in time
    $starttodate = date('d-m-y', $starttotime); // formatting date

    // check if start date and end date are similar
    if ($variables['element']['#items'][0]['value'] == $variables['element']['#items'][0]['value2']) {
      // HERE I NEED TO CHECK THE OTHER FIELD
      if (HERE THE FIELD ONE DAY == 0) {
        $variables['items'][0]['#markup'] = $starttodate." - One day";
      } else {
        $variables['items'][0]['#markup'] = $starttodate." - On air";}
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey there, I don't quite understand your question.  What's this 2nd field you're trying to check (the boolean, I'm assuming)?  I can see your question is somehow related to it, but am not quite getting what the problem is....

Comment: I've got one field date and one single checkbox. The single checkbox is to say "one day". The field date can collect start and end. I need to override the end date if the checkbox "one day" is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_field()` is invoked while rendering a single field, but (basing on the documentation for [field.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)) `$variables['element']['#object']` is the entity object to which the field is attached. Through that, you can get the value of the other field you are looking for.

Comment: May you do an example please?